# Trinidad with Facelets cause Stackoverflow

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish-3, facelets, trinidad

I'm in the middle of learning Java EE with Trinidad but ran into some problem. The Trinidad 2.x examples use JSPX while their old demo site use pure JSF (XHTML).  When I try to write the a test page using Facelets in XHTML, I kept getting java.lang.stackoverflowerror.  I'm not sure if it's a configuration issue or a syntax error.

I'm using Glassfish V3, MySQL 5.6, JSF 2.1 (Apache MyFace) , Apache Trinidad 2.0. And I follow most of this guide: http://jianmingli.com/wp/?p=3813

**Stack Trace** I omitted the rest of the log because it's too long

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.net.URLStreamHandler.equals(URLStreamHandler.java:331)
    at java.net.URL.equals(URL.java:862)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:995)
    at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache.get(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:95)
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"      xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>jsf2.myfaces2.trinidad2.one</display-name>

    <!-- ================= JSF Settings ================= -->
    <!-- Faces Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Faces Servlet Mappings -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- resource loader servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Important: You must include this adf mapping even though you are not 
        using ADF features. Without this mapping, JSF navigation will fail! -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/adf/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- setting the project stage to be DEVELOPMENT -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Use client-side state saving. In Trinidad, it is an optimized, token-based 
        mechanism that is almost always a better choice than the standard JSF server-side 
        state saving. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
        <!--param-value> server</param-value -->
    </context-param>


    <!-- ================= Trinidad Settings ================= -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.USE_APPLICATION_VIEW_CACHE</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.CHANGE_PERSISTENCE</param-name>
        <param-value>session</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.ALTERNATE_VIEW_HANDLER</param-name>
        <!-- TrinidadFaceletViewHander must be the alternate view handler if SessionChangeManager 
            is used -->
        <param-value>org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.facelets.TrinidadFaceletViewHandler</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <!--Unfortunately, Facelets provides no hook for plugging the PageResolver 
            into the logic handling "facelets.VIEW_MAPPINGS". You should leave "facelets.VIEW_MAPPINGS" 
            unset and use "org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.FACELETS_VIEW_MAPPINGS" instead. -->
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.FACELETS_VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
        <param-value>*.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>trinidad</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>trinidad</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:trh="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/html"
    xmlns:tr="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad">

<ui:composition template="" >
        <tr:table value="#{userTable.userList}" var="row">
            <tr:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <tr:outputText value="User Name" />
                </f:facet>
                <tr:outputText value="#{row.username}" />
            </tr:column>
            <tr:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <tr:outputText value="Password" />
                </f:facet>
                <tr:outputText value="#{row.password}" />
            </tr:column>
        </tr:table>
</ui:composition>

</html>
```

**index.jspx** This works when I configure the "javax.faces.FACELETS_VIEW_MAPPINGS" to *.jspx and omit the Trinidad Facelets specific configuration in web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:trh="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/html"
          xmlns:tr="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad">
    <f:view>
        <tr:document>
            <tr:table value="#{userTable.userList}" var="row">
                <tr:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <tr:outputText value="User Name" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <tr:outputText value="#{row.username}" />
                </tr:column>
                <tr:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <tr:outputText value="Password" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <tr:outputText value="#{row.password}" />
                </tr:column>
            </tr:table>
        </tr:document>
    </f:view>
</jsp:root>
```

Comment: This exception could happen when you map `Faces Servlet` to *.jsf , and call you file (psychically) myFile.jsf (instead of myFile.xhtml)...

Comment: Faces Servlet had *.jsf in the URL Pattern but I removed it and also renamed the file to .xhtml instead of .jsf.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed and I believe the **ui:composition template=""** was the cause of the StackOverFlowError.  Once I removed the **template=""** bit, it worked.  In addition, I came across the following in Apache Trinidad's mail archive regarding configuring web.xml for Trinidad 2.0 and Facelet:

> You do not need to have an entry for ALTERNATE_VIEW_HANDLER with Trinidad 2.0.
>
> You are getting the error because Trinidad is not yet compatible with
> partial state saving in JSF 2.0.
> Since partial state saving is enabled by default when Facelets are used,
> you need to explicitly disable it.
> Add the following context parameter in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

[Link to Apache Trinidad mail post](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/myfaces-users/201101.mbox/%3C4D3F4F0A.5020803@oracle.com%3E)

Answer (score 0):

Trinidad appears to cause a `StackOverflowError` when you use a relative path to a template in Faceletes. In your case, removing the extraneous `template=""` attribute from `ui:component` fixed the issue. In my case, I was actually using templates in my view, so I could not remove the attribute. Instead, I was able to work around the issue by **using the absolute path to the template view**.

For example, with the following view structure:

```
/views/template.xhtml
/view/index.xhtml
```

In **`index.xhtml`**, providing a relative path to **`template.xhtml`** causes a `StackOverflowError`:

```
<f:view
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <ui:include src="template.xhtml" />
</f:view>
```

Changing to the absolute path of `/views/template.xhtml` fixes the `StackOverflowError`:

```
<f:view
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <ui:include src="/views/template.xhtml" />
</f:view>
```

Comment: Trinidad appears to be unmaintained now: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TRINIDAD-2567